# HStack to get the actual width position on the UIScreen up to the left edge

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to use HStack to get the actual width position on the UIScreen up to the left edge of the background of the text "Apple". What should I do?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("SwiftUI")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(width:150)
                .background(Color.green)
            Text("Apple")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(width:200)
                .background(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a ruler.

Comment: Does it mean that there is no way to get it programmatically like .frame (in: .global) .midX --UIScreen.main.bounds.width on the view?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What exactly are you trying to get the width of?

Comment: I want to get the numerical value of the position up to Text ("Apple") on the view.